# How to compare date time in an anonymous entity type using LINQ. Entities does not recognize the method ToDateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an anonymous entity created like so :

```
var Results = (from c in db.SlotConfig
                        join dm in db.DailyMeters on
                             new { c.SlotID, c.SiteID } equals new { dm.SlotID, dm.SiteID }
                        select new {
                            Location = c.Location,
                            Manufacturer = c.ManufacturerName,
                            GameName = c.GameName,
                            GamingDay = dm.GamingDay,
                            ... 
                        });
```

where gaming day is a nullable DateTime(DateTime?).

Later on I have to get only the Results for a specific gaming day, thus using

`var startResults = Results.Where(r => r.GamingDay.Value == Convert.ToDateTime("2018-06-11 00:00:00.000"));` for example and it fires the exception.

When I do something like `Results = Results.Where(m => m.SiteID == 1)` it works perfectly fine. SiteID is nullable int, so I guess it works on the primitive types.

I checked for similar cases, but really nowhere is explained why it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the exception you're getting is something like "LINQ Entities doesn't know the Convert.ToDateTime()"? It's totaly normal, because Entity Framework is trying to translate your expression into a SQL Query, but Convert.ToDateTime doesn't exists in SQL (or not that way...). So you have to create your DateTime **before** passing it to your query.

Try something like that:

```
var myDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2018-06-11 00:00:00.000");
var startResults = Results.Where(r => r.GamingDay.Value == myDate);
```

And it should do the tricks.

A little explanation: with that way, you're passing to EF a value with a known type (here it's DateTime), not a function, so it's "easier" for EF to translate your expression into a SQL query.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying the exception more clearly. You are correct, that was the problem... trying to be cheeky with queries sometimes bites you in the ass =)